# Dependency Injection: cannot convert from 'Service' to 'System.Type'

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a scope in the Startup Class but for some reasons I get this error.

> cannot convert from 'service' to 'System.Type'
>
> cannot convert from 'Iservice' to 'System.Type'

I've also checked if I've injected the service correctly in all the other classes.

Here's the code

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IService Iservice;
    private readonly Service service;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IService Iservice, Service service)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        this.Iservice = Iservice;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connectionstring")));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

       // This is where I get the error
        services.AddScoped(Iservice, service);
    }
```

This seems like a beginner question so I'm sorry if it is.

Comment: Whats IService and Service and why are you injecting in Startup file?

Comment: Because Startup's constructor is fired before ConfigureServices method. You can not inject service before ConfigureServices

Comment: I am guessing you meant to use `services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();`. However, you cannot inject into the `Startup` constructor

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the info. Seems to me that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: `AddScoped` needs to know the types of  `IService` and `service` not instances of them